# How to allow NGINX to buffer for multiple Django App Servers

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

How can one allow NGINX to buffer client requests for multiple Django App Servers that all run a WSGI server like Gunicorn? What do I need to change in the config files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use nginx's [upstream](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpUpstreamModule#upstream) option to define a pool of application servers; when you proxy_pass, you can proxy_pass to the named upstream:

```
upstream my-upstream {
 server 127.0.0.1:9000;
 server 127.0.0.1:9001;
}

location / {
  proxy_pass http://my-upstream;
}
```

Unless you specify otherwise, requests will be round-robined between the different upstream servers.

Comment: what is the proxy_pass? say for example I have a load balancer between the two servers, would the url of the load balancer be the proxy_pass?

Comment: In that case your load balancer would be the server inside your upstream - if you were running more than one load balancer, you'd configure more servers with the different load balancers.

Comment: sorry for being unclear, what if the Load Balancers we're in front of the nginx servers? So LOAD BALANCER ---> NGINX SERVERS----> DJANGO APP SERVERS

Comment: In that case you'd configure the nginx upstream to point to the django app servers, and the load balancer to point to nginx.

Answer (score 0):

```
upstream my-upstream {
 least_conn;
 server 127.0.0.1:9000;
 server 127.0.0.1:9001;
}
location / {
  proxy_pass http://my-upstream;
}
```

Let Assume you are using 4 sever when your server 1 is down then nginx will intelligently shift your next request to your next available serve, once server 1 is up then your next request will be send again in server 1. Actually nginx use round robin algorithm to shifting the request.

```
upstream my-upstream {
 ip_hash;
 server 127.0.0.1:9000;
 server 127.0.0.1:9001;
}

location / {
  proxy_pass http://my-upstream;
}
```

In this case for previous scenario won't be same, Like we will always get response from server 1 and when our server 1 is down then it goes to server 2 and then when it is up that time is will response server 1 again.